# MySQL error - You have an error in your SQL syntax near line 1

Tags: mysql

Having an issue with MySQL.  here is the error I am getting:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I have tracked in down to the following line

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT prog.* FROM members as memb LEFT JOIN user_program as prog USING (ID) WHERE memb.Username='".mysql_escape_string($_SESSION['loggedin'])."' && program_id={$Global['program']}") or die('The Matrix is on fiya'.mysql_error());
```

However I am unsure of what is causing it to fail.

Comment: You should print out the resulting string to see what is really being passed into MySQL.

Comment: The mysql extension is deprecated. You should change over to PDO or mysqli at the very least. You should print out your query to make sure you have all the correct variables.

Comment: This is not my code and I do not claim to be much of a mysql guru. I am not sure what you mean by print out the resulting string. The error prevents anything from going further. I am not sure how I could PRINT $result  I did a query directly in PHPMyAdmin and it gave the same error message.

Comment: @ChrisHenry what do you mean by the "MySQL extension is deprecated"? What extension?

Comment: The mysql* functions are not part of core php. They are instead implmented as an extension. They were the first ones created, and have been replaced by newer, faster extensions, PDO, and mysqli. For reference, see this. http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should it be `$GLOBALS['program']` instead of `$Global['program']`?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Still no luck though. Yes. It is $Global and not $GLOBALS